# How to send data from the form and run another function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to send post data via ajax in such a way as not to get a return result. I want to call the myfunction () function if the connection to the script succeeds. I tried to get this effect through success in ajax. Unfortunately, it failed. Do you have any idea how to do it?

```js
$(function(){
    $('#send').click(function(){
        var info = 'my info';
        var website = $('#website').val().trim();
        if (website.length>0){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'file.php',
                data: {
                    url: website,
                    info: info
                },
                success: function(){
                    myfunction();
                } 
            });
        
        }
    
    });
    
    function myfunction(){
        alert('My function alert');
        //other code
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="website" />
<input type="submit" value="add website" id="send" />
```

Comment: What happen file.php? What do you get if you do `success: function(response) { console.log(response); }` ? Do you go in your success part or not?

Comment: In the file file.php, it adds a record to the database

Comment: An Ajax call need a response from your php to go to the success part, add `echo 'ok';` for example in your .php and tell me if you can go to the success part of your ajax call

Comment: After adding the echo works :), thanks

Comment: Glad to help :) Don't know if I should post an anwser for this